# Setting repeating alarm to auto update appwidget listview

Tags: android, android-widget

Android ICS: Created an app widget with custom List View, now I want to update the views periodically say every day @ 7 AM. I tried `AlarmManager.setRepeating()`, but didn't work. Is there any other way to do this? I am using `RemoteViewsServices` and `RemoteViewsFactory` to build the views for appwidget.